# Stored Procedure Storing 0 in Auto increment column in Table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following table where ProspectCode is Identity Not Null

```
Table LeadMastersNew

ProspectCode    int 
CompanyName nvarchar(50)    
PersonName  nvarchar(50)    
Designation nvarchar(50)
Number  nvarchar(50)    
Number2 nvarchar(50)    
Emailaddress    nvarchar(50)    
Address nvarchar(MAX)   
Address2    nvarchar(MAX)
CityName    nvarchar(50)    
State   nvarchar(50)    
PinNumber   nvarchar(50)    
Product nvarchar(50)    
RemarkNote  nvarchar(MAX)
```

The issue which I am facing lately is that when I am storing records to the above table using stored procedure,ProspectCode is always set to 0 for all the rows that I add.I have 160 Records in the above table,But when I add new Record, its ProspectCode is set to 0 for all the record that I add.

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Proc_InsertLeads]

 @ProspectCode nvarchar(50),@CompanyName nvarchar(50),@PersonName nvarchar(50),@Designation nvarchar(50),@Number nvarchar(50),  
 @Number2 nvarchar(50),@Emailaddress nvarchar(50),@Address nvarchar(MAX),@Address2 nvarchar(MAX),   
 @CityName nvarchar(50),@State nvarchar(50),@PinNumber nvarchar(50),@Product nvarchar(50),@RemarkNote nvarchar(MAX)

 AS

 BEGIN

      SET IDENTITY_INSERT LeadMastersNew ON;

      INSERT INTO LeadMastersNew
      (ProspectCode,CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,Emailaddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote) 
      VALUES(@ProspectCode,@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@Emailaddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote) 

      INSERT INTO LoggerLeadMasters
      (ProspectCode,CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,Emailaddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote,Activity,ActivityTime) 
      VALUES(@ProspectCode,@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@Emailaddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote,'New Record Added',getdate()) 

      SET IDENTITY_INSERT LeadMastersNew OFF;

END  


EXEC Proc_InsertLeads'ABc','Mr abc','MD','PhoneNumber','','abc@abcindia.com','xyz','','Mumbai','Maharashtra','400059','Abc', 'Abc'

Sets ProspectCode to 0
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Do I have to change my stored Procedure or Table Schema?

Thanks

Comment: "Do I have to change my stored Procedure" - you expect an answer when you've not shown us *any* of the code in that stored procedure?

Comment: Is ProspectCode set to auto-increment?

Comment: Sorry @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'll Update my question

Comment: Don't expose your business in global forums, you can change business terms with dummy terms.

Comment: Those are dummy terms @AnkushMadankar

Comment: You're using identity insert, so the identity column will be whatever is set, not the auto incremented value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an identity column to assign numbers automatically, the thing you really *shouldn't* be doing is setting [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188059.aspx) to `ON`. Turning that setting on says to SQL Server "trust me, **I'll** provide the values in the identity column".

You probably want code something like:

```
BEGIN

     DECLARE @NewID int

      INSERT INTO LeadMastersNew
      (/*ProspectCode,*/CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,Emailaddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote) 
      VALUES(/*@ProspectCode,*/@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@Emailaddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote) 

     SET @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

      INSERT INTO LoggerLeadMasters
      (ProspectCode,CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,Emailaddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote,Activity,ActivityTime) 
      VALUES(@NewID ,@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@Emailaddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote,'New Record Added',getdate()) 

END
```

This may not work exactly first time since I can't reconcile the code you've shown with how you're calling it. If `ProspectCode` is indeed an `int` column and you're actually trying to insert an `nvarchar` value of `'Choice Brokers'`, you should be getting an error.

Comment: @user2614235 we understand that you are passing values from C#; it isn't clear what you want us to make from that comment; what part of this (very clear) answer do you feel doesn't answer your question? Because I think it does: basically, *don't do that*

Comment: Thanks a lot Damien your solution helped 

@MarcGravell Thanks a lot,next time i'll be more precise while asking questions...

Answer (score 2):

you don't need identity_insert if you set autoincrement

remove rows

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LeadMastersNew ON;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LeadMastersNew OFF;

and it should work

Comment: @user2614235 "didn't work" is almost useless as a statement; *what happened*? I fully agree with Ash here; you're doing something *very wrong* if you are routinely using `IDENTITY_INSERT`. That has *very limited* valid use-cases, and I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: @MarcGravell I Removed 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LeadMastersNew ON;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LeadMastersNew OFF;

But The ProspectCode stores Autoincrement value as 0

Comment: @user2614235 that tells us what you tried; it does not tell us *what happened*; I'm guessing it told you not to try to assign to `ProspectCode`: it is right - see Damien's answer

Answer (score 2):

Here `ProspectCode` must set to `Auto-increment` since it is identity column for table. So basically in store procedure you must remove input parameter `@ProspectCode` and while inserting new row don't ON OFF `IDENTITY_INSERT` on table, final store procedure look like:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Proc_InsertLeads]

@CompanyName nvarchar(50),@PersonName nvarchar(50),@Designation nvarchar(50),@Number nvarchar(50), 
@Number2 nvarchar(50),@Emailaddress nvarchar(50),@Address nvarchar(MAX),@Address2 nvarchar(MAX),
@CityName nvarchar(50),@State nvarchar(50),@PinNumber nvarchar(50),@Product nvarchar(50),@RemarkNote nvarchar(MAX)

 AS

 BEGIN

  DECALRE @ID INT = 0

  INSERT INTO LeadMastersNew
  (CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,Emailaddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote) 
  VALUES(@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@Emailaddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote) 

  SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

  INSERT INTO LoggerLeadMasters
  (ProspectCode,CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,Emailaddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote,Activity,ActivityTime) 
  VALUES(@ID,@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@Emailaddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote,'New Record Added',getdate()) 


END
```

Here I am using `@ID` parameter to find newly inserted `ProspectCode` in table `LeadMastersNew` which will used in table `LoggerLeadMasters` as `ProspectCode`.

Comment: Note that `@@IDENTITY` is not recommended; if possible, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead, as it is not impacted / confused by things like triggers

Comment: @MarcGravell Right, edited answer, anything else which affect `@@identity` global variable in sql server rather than triggers?